# Permalink of specific post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

Below the code I have on my page tot display the permalink of q specific post in Wordpress. It works, but I have the feeling it can be easier. Can somebody explain how?

```
$post_id      = 26;  // post id
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title        = $queried_post->post_title;
$content      = $queried_post->post_content;
$perma        = get_permalink($post_id);

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
}

echo '<a href="' . $perma . '" title="' . $title . '">';
echo $title;
echo '</a>';
echo '<img width="100%" src="' . $image_src[0] . '">'; 
echo $content;
```

Comment: I don't understand... what can be easier than `
    $perma = get_permalink($post_id);`

Comment: sorry, I meant the echo

Comment: echo '<a href="' . $perma . '" title="' . $title . '">';
    echo $title;
    echo '</a>';

Comment: Oh, you want to shorten those 3 lines? See answer below. Use "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code seems ok. However there are some improvements that can be made.
For example, when you have the `$queried_post` object, you don't need to create additional variables for content and title. You can use this object properties to get the values.

Also you can use wordpress [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) to show featured image.
Some formatting and it's almost perfect.

```
$post_id      = 26;  // post id
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); 

echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . $queried_post->post_title . '">';
    echo $queried_post->post_title;
echo '</a>';

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full', array('width' => '100%') );
}

echo $queried_post->post_content;
```

Comment: thx for the explanation and the code! This works fine and it's a easier code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$post_id = 26; 
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post_id) ) 
{
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(    get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id),’thumbnail’ );
}

echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink($post_id) . '" title="' .get_the_title($post_id). '">';
echo get_the_title($post_id);
echo '</a>';
echo '<img width="100%" src="' . $image_src[0] . '">'; 
echo get_the_content($post_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, if you want to simplify this line:

```
 echo '<a href="' . $perma . '" title="' . $title . '">';
 echo $title;
 echo '</a>';
```

You could do:

```
echo '<a href="' . $perma . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a>';
```

So replacing multiple echo; with the "." to 'continue' without breaks.